# Error 405 ajax metodo no permitido

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Hola tengo el siguiente código javascript ajax y php:

```
<?php 

    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $mensaje=$_POST['mensaje'];

    $respuesta=array(
        'nombre'=>$nombre,
        'email'=>$email,
        'mensaje'=>$mensaje
    );
    echo json_encode($respuesta);
?>
```

Y el siguiente de ajax:

```
'use strict';

/* APARTADO 1 JAVASCRIPT */



// Identificamos el texto que deseamos cambiar
var texto = document.querySelector('.texto-header h2');

//Creamos un evento de tipo click para cambiar el texto una vez pulsado sobre él mediante una función anónima
texto.addEventListener('click', function () {
    this.innerHTML = 'Has pulsado sobre el título';
});


/* Apartado 2 de javascript: Creando un objeto */

// El primer paso es añadir un evento al formulario cuyi id es formularioContactos y extraer los datos de los inputs que introduce el usuario
var formularioContactos = document.querySelector('#formularioContactos')
formularioContactos.addEventListener('submit', validarFrm);

function validarFrm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //Para evitar leer valores en blancos o evitar que el usuario teclee espacio usamos trim()
    var nombre = document.querySelector('#nombre').value.trim(),
        email = document.querySelector('#email').value.trim(),
        mensaje = document.querySelector('#mensaje').value.trim(),
        accion=document.querySelector('#accion').value;



    // Validamos que el frm no vaya vacío
    if (nombre === '' || email === '' || mensaje === '') {
        alert('Todos los campos son obligatorios', 'error');
    } else {

        //Si el formulario contiene datos creamos un objeto de formData
        const datos = new FormData();

        // Añadimos al objeto datos mediante append lo que el usuario mado en el formulario
        datos.append('nombre', nombre);
        datos.append('email', email);
        datos.append('mensaje', mensaje);
        datos.append('accion',accion);

        if (accion==='enviar') {
            insertar(datos);
        }





    }


    function insertar(datos){

        /* Lamado a ajax.

        creación del objeto
        */
        const xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();

        /* Apertura de la conexion */
        xhr.open('POST','modelo-datos.php',true);

        /* Paso de datos */
        xhr.onload=function(){

             if(this.status===200){

                /* El objeto xhr devuelve un string----------------------*/
                //console.log(xhr.responseText);

                //respuesta=JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                //Imprimir en consola todos los datos del objeto
                console.log(respuesta);



                //Identificar el div donde está el formulario para añadirlo después
                var contenedor = document.querySelector('.formulario-contacto');

                //Creamos el div donde agregaremos los datos del contacto y el titulo
                var impresion = document.createElement('div'),
                    titulo = document.createElement('h2');


                titulo.innerHTML = "Datos insertados";
                impresion.appendChild(titulo);

                //Creamos la lista que contiene los datos
                var lista_datos = document.createElement('ul');
                lista_datos.innerHTML = `
                <li>${nombre}</li>
                <li>${email}</li>
                <li>${mensaje}</li>
                `;

                impresion.appendChild(lista_datos);
                contenedor.appendChild(impresion);




            }
        }

        /* Envío de datos-------------- */
        xhr.send(datos);

    }

}
```

Estoy intentando comunicar un archivo de javascript mediante ajax con uno php. En el archivo javascript leo los datos que se envían en un formulario a traves de unas variables. Luego mediante un formData envio mediante ajax al archivo php donde lo devuelvo a ajax con un json. Pero me aparece este error:

[image: captura]

Alguien puede darme una mano con ese error porfa. Lo que quiero es que se imprima en consola lo que se envía de php a ajax.

Comment: Los códigos de respuesta 40X no son errores del servidor, son del cliente. Es decir, estás tratando de hacer un request POST hacia un endpoint que no lo tiene implementado. En otras palabras, ese endpoint no recibe POSTs.

Comment: Cesar entonces que debo corregir

Comment: Lo que tienes que hacer es asegurarte de que en `modelo-datos.php` hayas implementado el POST. ¿Tal vez te hayas equivocado y haz implementado un GET? Revisa el código.